# How to mock method to pass test in golang

Tags: unit-testing, go, mocking

I'm setting unit test for api(golang).
It seems to use mocking. But I don't understand how to code to success.

```
article
  ├ client
  ├ api
  │  ├ main.go
  │  ├ contoroller
  │  │    ├ contoroller.go
  │  │    └ contoroller_test.go
  │  ├ service
  │  │    ├ service.go
  │  │    └ service_test.go
  │  ├ dao
  │  │    ├ dao.go
  │  │    └ dao_test.go
  │  ├ s3
  │  │    ├ s3.go
  │  │    └ s3_test.go
  │  ├ go.mod 
  │  ├ go.sum
  │  └ Dockerfile
  ├ nginx
  └ docker-compose.yml
```

Now I'm trying to set `dao_test.go`
But it fails because `dao.go` calls method from `s3.dao`.

dao_test.go

```golang
package dao

// import

type DaoSuite struct {
    suite.Suite
    db   *sql.DB
    mock sqlmock.Sqlmock
    dao  *Dao
    s3   *s3.S3
}

func (s *DaoSuite) SetupTest() {

    var err error
    s.db, s.mock, err = sqlmock.New()
    s.Require().NoError(err)
    s.dao = NewDao(s.db, s.s3)
}

func (s *DaoSuite) TestDeleteArticleDao() {

    // some method

    // here test fails because DeleteArticleDao calls method from another package.
    s.dao.DeleteArticleDao("1")

}

func (s *DaoSuite) TearDownTest() {
    s.db.Close()
    s.Assert().NoError(s.mock.ExpectationsWereMet())
}
```

dao.go

```golang
package dao

// import

type Dao struct {
    database *sql.DB
    s3       *s3.S3
}

func NewDao(database *sql.DB, s3 *s3.S3) *Dao {
    objs := &Dao{database: database, s3: s3}
    return objs
}

func (d *Dao) DeleteArticleDao(id string) {
    //generate imageName

    //here calls method in package s3
    //here test fails 
    d.s3.DeleteS3Image(imageName)

}
```

s3.go

```golang
package s3

//import

type S3 struct {
    APPID  string
    SECRET string
}

type DaoInterface interface {
    DeleteS3Image(imageName util.ImageName) error
}

func NewS3(appid, secret string) *S3 {
    objs := &S3{APPID: appid, SECRET: secret}
    return objs
}


func (objs *S3) DeleteS3Image(imageName util.ImageName) error {
    // method
}
```

The full source code is here(fix-test-dao):
 
https://github.com/jpskgc/article/tree/fix-test-dao

I expect the test success in `dao_test.go`.
But the actual is it fails because `dao.go` calls method from `s3 package`.
I want to know how to mock `DeleteS3Image` in package s3 to avoid error and success test.

Here is the error when running `go test -v` at `dao_test.go`.

```
$ go test -v
--- FAIL: TestDaoSuite (0.00s)
    --- FAIL: TestDaoSuite/TestDeleteArticleDao (0.00s)
        dao_test.go:221: 
                Error Trace:    dao_test.go:221
                                                        suite.go:122
                                                        panic.go:522
                                                        panic.go:82
                                                        signal_unix.go:390
                                                        s3.go:66
                                                        dao.go:74
                                                        dao_test.go:156
                Error:          Received unexpected error:
                                there is a remaining expectation which was not matched: ExpectedBegin => expecting database transaction Begin
                Test:           TestDaoSuite/TestDeleteArticleDao
        suite.go:61: test panicked: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
```

Comment: the error is on `suite.go` line `6`, can you share the particular code please

Comment: `suite.go` is common package. here is https://github.com/stretchr/testify/blob/master/suite/suite.go#L6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your setup you do call `s.dao = NewDao(s.db, s.s3)` however you've never initialized `s.s3` to anything, so `s.dao.s3` remains `nil` and that's why `d.s3.DeleteS3Image(imageName)` panics.

---

In Go to be able to mock a method, the value on which the method is called must be an interface, not a concrete type. Put another way, it is *not* possible to mock a concrete method in Go.

So with a type like this:

```
type Dao struct {
    database *sql.DB
    s3       *s3.S3
}
```

you simply *cannot* mock `s3`.

What you can do, is change the type of the `s3` field to an interface type, you already have one ready (`s3.DaoInterface`).

```
type Dao struct {
    database *sql.DB
    s3       s3.DaoInterface
}
```

now you *can* mock the `s3` field.

What's left is for you to implement your mock and make sure that the `s3` field is set to an instance of the mock implementation during test setup.

```
type MockS3 struct{}

func (MockS3) DeleteS3Image(imageName util.ImageName) error {
    // do whatever
    return nil
}

func (s *DaoSuite) SetupTest() {

    var err error
    s.db, s.mock, err = sqlmock.New()
    s.Require().NoError(err)
    s.dao = NewDao(s.db, s.s3)
    s.dao.s3 = MockS3{} // <- don't forget about me
}
```

It is up to you how you implement the mock, but if you're new to mocks I would recommend you take a look at https://github.com/golang/mock to help you with generating mocks.

Comment: Thanks for advice. when I follow this advice, I face compile error issue in dao_test.go. Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57840793/cannot-use-mockdaointerface-literal-type-mockdaointerface-as-type-s3-daointerf

Comment: @jpskgc.v5 You can see in my example I've implemented `DeleteS3Image` on a non-pointer `MockS3` therefore I can use `MockS3{}`. In your version you've implemented the method on a pointer `*MockDaoInterface` therefore you have to use `&MockDaoInterface{}`.